# Dagger AndroidInjection with Userscope

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I'm facing a problem with dagger 2.

I would like to have at least 2 components with 2 different scopes :

> - singleton
> - userscope

**UserScope** should be created when user has successfully logged in.

I have made a presenter factory which will provide fully injected presenter using binding and **@Inject** constructor :

```
    @Singleton
public class PresenterFactory {

    private final Map<Class<? extends Presenter>, Provider<Presenter>> mCreators;

    @Inject
    public PresenterFactory(Map<Class<? extends Presenter>, Provider<Presenter>> creators) {
        mCreators = creators;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a fully injected presenter. If no presenter can be instantiated, an exception is thrown.
     *
     * @param presenterClass Presenter class.
     * @param <T>            Presenter instance.
     * @return Instance of presenter.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends Presenter> T create(Class<T> presenterClass) {
        Provider<Presenter> presenterProvider = mCreators.get(presenterClass);
        if (presenterProvider == null) {
            for (Map.Entry<Class<? extends Presenter>, Provider<Presenter>> entry : mCreators.entrySet()) {
                if (presenterClass.isAssignableFrom(entry.getKey())) {
                    presenterProvider = entry.getValue();
                }
            }
        }

        if (presenterProvider == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Class " + presenterClass + " seems not provided");
        }

        try {
            return (T) presenterProvider.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            MVPLogger.e("PresenterFactory", e.getMessage(), e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Actually when I want to inject activities and presenters in the singleton scope, everything works well but I don't manage to use a user scope.
My code is :

**Application :**

```
public class MVPApplication extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {

    private static AppComponent mAppComponent;

    private static UserComponent mUserComponent;

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        initializeInjector();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the injector.
     */
    private void initializeInjector() {
        mAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .application(this)
            .build();

        mAppComponent.inject(this);
    }

    public static void makeUserComponent(){
        mUserComponent = mAppComponent.createUserComponent().build();
    }

    public static UserComponent getUserComponent(){
        return mUserComponent;
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

**AppComponent :**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidInjectionModule.class,
        ActivityBindingModule.class,
        CoreModule.class,
        AppModule.class,
        PresenterModule.class
})
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(MVPApplication application);

    UserComponent.Builder createUserComponent();

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        /** Add the application object to the graph. */
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(MVPApplication application);

        /** Build the component. */
        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

**ActivityBindingModule :**

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBindingModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract MainActivity contributeMainActivity();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract UserActivity contributeUserActivity();
}
```

CoreModule (from another project module) :

```
@Module
public class CoreModule {

    /**
     * Provides the presenter cache.
     *
     * @return Presenter cache.
     */
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public PresenterCache getPresenterCache(){
        return new PresenterCache();
    }
}
```

**AppModule :**

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public TaskManager getTaskManager() {
        return new TaskManager();
    }
}
```

**PresenterModule :**

```
@Module
public abstract class PresenterModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @PresenterKey(MainPresenter.class)
    abstract Presenter bindMainPresenter(MainPresenter presenter);
}
```

**UserComponent :**

```
@UserScope
@Subcomponent(modules = {
        UserModule.class,
        UserPresenterModule.class,

})
public interface UserComponent {

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {
        UserComponent build();
    }
}
```

**UserModule :**

```
@Module
public class UserModule {

    @Provides
    @UserScope
    @Named("TestString")
    public String getString(){
        return "Injected";
    }
}
```

**UserPresenterModule :**

```
@Module
public abstract class UserPresenterModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @PresenterKey(UserPresenter.class)
    abstract Presenter bindUserPresenter(UserPresenter presenter);
}
```

I am injecting my activities using `AndroidInjection.inject(this);`

My **UserPresenter** is injected with

```
@Inject
public UserPresenter(TaskManager taskManager, @Named("testString") String test) 
{
    mTaskManager = taskManager;
    mString = test;
}
```

I know I am missing something but I can't figure what and where. I would like to avoid doing something like

```
public UserPresenter(){
     MVPApplication.getUserComponent().inject(this);
}
```

To keep my presenter easily testable with injected constructor.

The error I get is : Class class UserPresenter seems not provided

Thank you for your help.